# A styled component doesn't recognize a global JS variable

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm having trouble with some react component's style. My goal is to display three sets of a radio button and four squares, each (square) filled with a different color, i'm using styled-components and my code is the following:

```
const colorArr = ["#dc802c","#363550","#f6f6f6","#eac9b5",
                  "#092532","#adc9b7","#89c9b8","#e1ffc2",
                  "#222831","#4f8a8b","#eeeeee","#fbd46d"];

var colorString = "";

let ColorContainer = styled.div
`
  border-radius: 4px; 
  border: 1em solid ${colorString};
`;

function giveColor(colorNum)
{
  colorString = colorArr[colorNum];
  return(<ColorContainer/>);
}

function Selector()
{
  return(
    <ThemesWrapper>
      <ThemeWrapper key="theme1">
        <input type="radio" name="theme1"/>
        {giveColor(0)}
        {giveColor(1)}
        {giveColor(2)}
        {giveColor(3)}
      </ThemeWrapper>
      <ThemeWrapper key="theme2">
        <input type="radio" name="theme2"/>
        {giveColor(4)}
        {giveColor(5)}
        {giveColor(6)}
        {giveColor(7)}
      </ThemeWrapper>
      <ThemeWrapper key="theme3">
        <input type="radio" name="theme3"/>
        {giveColor(8)}
        {giveColor(9)}
        {giveColor(10)}
        {giveColor(11)}
      </ThemeWrapper>
    </ThemesWrapper>
  );
}
```

I have console-logged the colorString and it shows the strings of the colors, so it seems the problem is in the ColorContainer, but i can't see it.

ThemesWrapper and Themesrapper just add some flex and justify the content. The result i get is three sets of four little squares displayed as i want but all of them with the same color and no radio button, i've tried a lot of things but nothing gives me the result i expect, i'm a noob in javascript, react and style-components so i would appreciate a lot your help.

Comment: You just changing the string value, how its related to changing the prop? Thats not how you use styled-components, please read the basics in docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See `styled-components` [docs](https://www.styled-components.com/) for how to use this library, you need to pass a callback for reading a prop, for example:

```
const colorArr = ["#dc802c", "#363550", "..."];

let ColorContainer = styled.div`
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1em solid ${(props) => props.color};
`;

function Selector({index}) {
  return <ColorContainer color={colorArr[index]} />;
}
```